# Adding data besides the old data instead of overwriting them with fs writeFile

Tags: javascript

I want to know how I add something with the writeFile instead of overwriting it.
This is what I expected:

```json
{
    "726623241984278589": {
        "322366672625467392": {
            "": {
                "Moderation": "Kick",
                "TargetID": "322366672625467392",
                "Moderator": "Bobosky#3914",
                "Reason": "Testing",
                "ID": "#ZAHVOJUZ"
            }
            "2": {
                "Moderation": "Kick",
                "TargetID": "322366672625467392",
                "Moderator": "Bobosky#3914",
                "Reason": "Testing",
                "ID": "#KX7OMT4S"
            },
            "3": {
                "Moderation": "Kick",
                "TargetID": "322366672625467392",
                "Moderator": "Bobosky#3914",
                "Reason": "Testing",
                "ID": "#LLV26ZV8"
            }
        }
    },
    "Count": {
        "322366672625467392": 0
    }
}
```

But it outputs like this:

```json
{
    "726623241984278589": {
        "322366672625467392": {
            "3": {
                "Moderation": "Kick",
                "TargetID": "322366672625467392",
                "Moderator": "Bobosky#3914",
                "Reason": "Testing",
                "ID": "#LLV26ZV8"
            }
        }
    },
    "Count": {
        "322366672625467392": 0
    }
}
```

And there is my code:

```js
if (!data['Count']) data['Count'] = {
    [TargetMember.id]: 0
};

data['Count'][TargetMember.id]++;
const Counter = data['Count'][TargetMember.id];

data[message.guild.id] = {
    [TargetMember.id]: {
        [Counter]: {
            Moderation: 'Kick',
            TargetID: `${TargetMember.id}`,
            Moderator: `${message.author.tag}`,
            Reason: `${Reason}`,
            ID: `#${ID}`
        }
    }
}

fs.writeFile("./data.json", JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

How can I add data besides of the old data instead of overwriting them?

PS: I didn't show all the codes since some of them are irrelevant to this question. And all the parmas works fine such as the TargetMember, reason etc. I just want to know why I can't add data instead of overwriting them. And the project is based on discord.js

Comment: fs.appendFile ??

Answer (score 1):

#### instead of writeFile method you have to use appendFile

```
fs.appendFile(path, data[, options], callback)

fs.appendFile("./data.json", JSON.stringify(data), (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

#### documentation:

> https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback